# Error in Vercel Server deploying GiHub repository

Tags: next.js

I have my portfolio coded in nextjs and when i had tried to upload to vercel free plan i got this erorrs:

**Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useContext')
at exports.useContext (/vercel/path0/node_modules/react/cjs/react.production.min.js:24:118)
at y (/vercel/path0/.next/server/chunks/487.js:1:12625)
at Wc (/usr/local/share/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:68:44)
at Zc (/usr/local/share/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:70:253)
at Z (/usr/local/share/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:76:89)
at $c (/usr/local/share/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:78:98)
at bd (/usr/local/share/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:77:404)
at Z (/usr/local/share/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:76:217)
at Zc (/usr/local/share/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:71:479)
at Z (/usr/local/share/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:76:89)
Error occurred prerendering page "/blog". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error**

I just tried to quit of my code my application Links to other pages like blog or github:

```
 <Link href="/" className="navbar-brand">
          Simple Portfolio
        </Link>
        <button
          className="navbar-toggler"
          type="button"
          data-bs-toggle="collapse"
          data-bs-target="#navbarNav"
          aria-controls="navbarNav"
          aria-expanded="false"
          aria-label="Toggle navigation"
        >
          <span className="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div className="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
          <ul className="navbar-nav ml-auto">
            <li className="nav-item">
              <Link
                href="/blog"
                className="nav-link active"
                aria-current="page"
              >
                Blog
              </Link>
            </li>
            <li className="nav-item">
              <Link href="/github" className="nav-link">
                Github
              </Link>
            </li>
          </ul>
```

This is the link: [text](https://portfolio-amber-omega-42.vercel.app)
As you can see we have "/", "github" and "blog" which are 3 pages.js in pages folder. removing this lines it works very fine and vercel can build my code.

what woul be the problem?